# Find users with same name on inner joined queries PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search, group-by, inner-join

I'm working on a search system very outdated in PHP+MySQL, now... The owner asked me to introduce two buttons to apply filters to the main query. First button should find only users with same first_name and last_name, the second one should find only users with same last_name.
Now ATM the query uses different joins (inner and left do get other informations from other tables)

```
$query = "
  SELECT s1.*,s2.first_name,s2.last_name,s2.email,s2.id as subscriber_id,s2.phone,s2.info,a.id as agency_id,a.info as agency_info,a.invoice as agency_invoice
  FROM subscription as s1
  LEFT JOIN agency as a
  ON s1.agency=a.id
  INNER JOIN subscriber as s2
  ON s1.subscriber=s2.id
  WHERE $matches AND s1.deleted=0
  ORDER BY s1.id DESC
  LIMIT $maxid,$limit
";
```

Everything works properbly but if I add clauses to group users by same full_name it returns only one result per fullname...

So if I have a table like this

```
+------------+-----------+
| first_name | last_name |
+------------+-----------+
| Foo        | Bar       |
| Foo        | Bar       |
| Bar        | Foo       |
| Bar        | Foo       |
| John       | Doe       |
+------------+-----------+
```

It returns

```
+------------+-----------+
| first_name | last_name |
+------------+-----------+
| Foo        | Bar       |
| Bar        | Foo       |
+------------+-----------+
```

Now... the clauses that I add into query are these (count and groupby)

```
$query = "
  SELECT s1.*,s2.first_name,s2.last_name,s2.email,s2.id as subscriber_id,s2.phone,s2.info,a.id as agency_id,a.info as agency_info,a.invoice as agency_invoice, Count(s2.*) AS Cnt
  FROM subscription as s1
  LEFT JOIN agency as a
  ON s1.agency=a.id
  INNER JOIN subscriber as s2
  ON s1.subscriber=s2.id
  WHERE $matches AND s1.deleted=0
  GROUP BY s2.first_name, s2.last_name HAVING Cnt>1
  ORDER BY s1.id DESC
  LIMIT $maxid,$limit
";
```

But as I've already said... it doesn't work and I don't know why... where am I wrong? Does it depend from joining? Is there a way to find a solution or with that query I need to find another solution? Please help me, I've tried other solutions but no way! :D

Comment: _“but if I add clauses to group users by same full_name it returns only one result per fullname”_ - that is what GROUP BY _does_, if you do not want that, then you do not want to group (or at least not by the current criterion) in the first place.

Comment: And if I want to get only results with same first_name and last_name... GROUP BY is the wrong option?

Comment: What is the exact output which you need... also mention the tables structure and data?

Comment: Basically the first table without John Doe... only dupliates users to better understand!